# JK flip flop timing diagram

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, homework, diagram, timing-analysis

Is this JK flip flop timing diagram for the Q output correct? I just want to make sure I didn't mess anything up.

[image: Timing diagram with instructions]

Answer (score 0):

You've missed one falling clock edge where J was active. Looks fine otherwise.

[image: Corrected solution]